# How to replace all given characters?

Tags: c#, regex, string, replaceall

I'm trying to write a method that *replaces all occurrences* of the characters in the input array (`charsToReplace`) with the `replacementCharacter` using regex. The version I have written *does not work* if the array contains any characters that *may change* the meaning of the regex pattern, such as `']'` or `'^'`.

```
public static string ReplaceAll(string str, char[] charsToReplace, char replacementCharacter)
{
    if(str.IsNullOrEmpty())
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }

    var pattern = $"[{new string(charsToReplace)}]";
    return Regex.Replace(str, pattern, replacementCharacter.ToString());
}
```

So `ReplaceAll("/]a", {'/', ']' }, 'a')` should return `"aaa"`.

Comment: Then you have to [escape these characters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside a character class, only 4 chars require escaping, `^`, `-`, `]` and `\`. **You can't use [`Regex.Escape`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape?view=netframework-4.8)** because it does not escape `-`and `]` as they are not "special" outside a character class. Note that `Regex.Escape` is meant to be used only for literal char (sequences) that are *outside* character classes.

An unescaped `]` char will *close your character class prematurely* and that is the main reason why your code does not work.

So, the fixed `pattern` variable definition can look like

```
var pattern = $"[{string.Concat(charsToReplace).Replace(@"\", @"\\").Replace("-", @"\-").Replace("^", @"\^").Replace("]", @"\]")}]";
```

See an [online C# demo](https://ideone.com/lcznQ1).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using *Linq*, not *regular expresions*:

```
using System.Linq;

...

public static string ReplaceAll(
  string str, char[] charsToReplace, char replacementCharacter) 
{
   // Please, note IsNullOrEmpty syntax
   // we should validate charsToReplace as well
   if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str) || null == charsToReplace || charsToReplace.Length <= 0)
     return str; // let's just do nothing (say, not turn null into empty string)

   return string.Concat(str.Select(c => charsToReplace.Contains(c) 
     ? replacementCharacter
     : c));
}
```

If you insist on `Regex` (note, that we should `Regex.Escape` chars within `charsToReplace`). However, according to the [manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape?view=netframework-4.8) `Regex.Escape` **doesn't escape** `-` and `[` which have *special meaning* within regular expression *brackets*.

```
public static string ReplaceAll(
  string str, char[] charsToReplace, char replacementCharacter) {

  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str) || null == charsToReplace || charsToReplace.Length <= 0)
    return str;

  string charsSet = string.Concat(charsToReplace
    .Select(c => new char[] { ']', '-' }.Contains(c) // in case of '-' and ']'
       ? $@"\{c}"                                    // escape them as well
       : Regex.Escape(c.ToString())));

  return Regex.Replace(
     str,
    $"[{charsSet}]+",
     m => new string(replacementCharacter, m.Length));
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. Here's a test I tried: `Assert.That(ReplaceAll("a^a[a]a/a", new char[] { '^', ']', '[', '/' }, 'x') == "axaxaxaxa");`

Comment: @Link: I see, thank you! `Regex.Escape` is *not enough* when we put chars within *brackets* `[...]`