# C# Regex.Escape() doesn't escape closing brackets "]"

Tags: c#, regex, linq

```
public static string GetRegexClass(IEnumerable<string> characters) =>
     $"[{string.Join("", characters.Select(Regex.Escape))}]";

var endingClass = GetRegexClass(new[] {"।", "॥", "]", "[", "|"});
```

The `endingClass` contains:`[।॥]\[\|]`

The problem is that it doesn't escape `]` it should be like: `[।॥\]\[\|]`. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Because  `Regex.Escape` only escapes the chars that need to be literal *outside the character class*. You need `$"[{string.Join("", characters.Select(x => x.Replace("\\", "\\\\").Replace("^", "\\^").Replace("-", "\\-").Replace("]", "\\]")))}]"`

Comment: Just found [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59681341/3832970), if you want to credit the solution, please visit the original thread.